# how to set multiple permission in MLCP -option_permissions

Tags: marklogic, mlcp

I use MLCP IMPORT option parameter for permissions.  But I getting an error at permissions. If I put "read" it works. However MLCP doesn't work if I combine "(read,update)". Please give me some hints.  Thanks in advance.

```
-output_permissions
"bib-read-role, (read,update),bib-insert-permission, update"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use it like this:

```
-output_permissions "bib-read-role,read,bib-read-role,update,bib-insert-permission,update"
```

HTH!