# Marklogic mlcp and optic query

Tags: marklogic, mlcp

Hi I am able to push data into MarkLogic using mlcp but on doing an optic query I get null as result. How can I receive a result from an optic query after pushing the data using mlcp and even after adding the schema? Or how do I map the schema with the mlcp pushing data?

Data loaded with this MLCP command:

> mlcp.sh import -host localhost -port 8000 -username admin -password admin -input_file_path C:\Users\sehajpalsinghj\Documents\DPHMJSOn\csv\1.csv -input_file_type delimited_text -document_type json -mode local -output_collections test

Comment: I'd start with checking document permissions of what you imported with MLCP. One typically runs that with some admin user, and it is easy to forget to apply `-output_permissions`. See here how to use that parameter: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46058091/918496

Comment: Have you confirmed that the TDE template matches a sample document?

Comment: Can you provide the optic query you're running and a sample document or two? There's not much we can do without those.

Comment: mlcp.sh import -host localhost -port 8000 -username admin  -password admin -input_file_path C:\Users\sehajpalsinghj\Documents\DPHMJSOn\csv\1.csv -input_file_type delimited_text -document_type json -mode local -output_collections test

Comment: also refer this link for the better understanding of the question  https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17363273

Comment: am i missing anything in the mlcp command so as to link it with the schema @DaveCassel

Answer (score 0):

Are you using TDE to get information from the documents into the index? Assuming so, your TDE template must specify the context (a path in the document) and may specify one or more collections. Since you're using MLCP to generate JSON documents from CSV, you will have very flat JSON: all the properties will be part of the root object. Specify one of those properties as the context. Use the [tde.nodeDataExtract](http://docs.marklogic.com/tde.nodeDataExtract) function to verify that the template is extracting from the documents what you think it should be extracting -- do this before trying to do anything with Optic.

Assuming you are using TDE, I highly recommend you read all the way through the [Template-Driven Extraction tutorial](http://developer.marklogic.com/learn/template-driven-extraction).